# How to restore deleted files and directories in a NTFS partition

Tags: linux, ntfs, data-recovery

The other day I deleted by mistake all files in a `NTFS` basic data partition using **rm -rf**. This partition is separated from `Microsoft reserved partition`, and `EFI system partition` among others, so I can boot my PC normally and select different OS at the GRUB2 menu. However, if I select to boot Windows 8.1 (stored in that partition) nothing happens, and the PC reboots.

I guess that partition table is OK, and I presume that it's possible to recover all files and the structure of directories they belonged to, so I would be able to restore and use that `NTFS` partition with Windows.

I think I can achieve this using a **debugfs**-like tool, but since file system is `NTFS` it seems to not work (I get `Bad magic number in superior-block while opening filesystem` error).

I also have read about other tools to recover files in `NTFS` such as **photorec**, but for what I've seen in some tutorials, it justs recovers files, and does not organise them as they were in their original state.

So the first question is: is it possible to recover not only the deleted files, but the structure of directories they had using Linux from a separated partition/disk? If affirmative, how?

Thank you.

Comment: So is for programming questions, not computer technical support.

Comment: You might find this article of help : http://askubuntu.com/questions/59968/recover-accidentally-removed-files-on-ntfs-partition . Good luck.

Comment: Have you already checked with Testdisk?

Comment: By the way, see the related answer here for the general case (both damaged and working NTFS): http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179

Comment: Using TestDisk, click through device and type to Advanced.. in partition selection, pay attention to the bottom for Undelete. Then select a different drive to save to. I believe its possible to write a script using fls from TestDisk to recover from a single directory if that is needed or when the TD single selection is tedious.. see this answer here: unix.stackexchange.com/a/390174/346155

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to get back the file system structure.

Recovery software typically gets the files from low level information on the hard disk. At that level, the data doesn't have the same structure like the common structure which we see in a file explorer.

Comment: This is totally not true. There are multiple ways to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Such as?

Comment: @ojchase such as the options I linked under the comments of the question, above. For your convenience, here's a link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179